# How to get the max ID for every Type every Date

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to keep the highest report id (**Report_ID**) for every type (**Types**) for every single date (**Date**)

Note: The data column has multiple dates, only 01.01.2021 is shown below.

```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM Table1 a
  JOIN (
    SELECT Date, MAX(Report_ID) as maxID
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Date) b 
  ON a.Report_ID = b.maxID
  WHERE a.Date = '2021-01-01'
  ORDER BY Date desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.report_id = (select max(t2.report_id)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.date = t.date and t2.type = t.type
                    );
```